# Como transformar um array de char em UTF-8?

Tags: array, c++, string, utf-8

Por exemplo, tenho um `char cadeia[300];`. Coloquei caracteres nela, agora quero transformá-la em UTF-8.

Comment: Da uma olhado neste link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573834/c-convert-string-or-char-to-wstring-or-wchar-t

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 1):

Nem tente fazer isto.

*Strings* com qualquer codificação *multibyte* são difíceis de manipular. A não ser que queira realmente se aventurar em algo bem trabalhoso, pegue uma biblioteca pronta para manipular este tipo de dado. Pode usar a [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/), pode usar o tipo [`wstring`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) se o seu compilador suportar.

Aí se usar isto, e precisar de *strings* sem ser UTF-8, use o tipo [`string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string).

Se usar estes tipos, não precisar usar `char *`  ou `char[]`. É altamente recomendável fazer isto.

Se realmente tiver um código legado que use `char *`, pode criar uma *string wide* assim:

```
wstring wcadeia(cadeia);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/String/Wstring.cpp).

Comment: Dependendo a plataforma, o iconv é uma forma de converter entre diferentes encodings em C